# How to automatically run this code

Tags: forms, calculator, onload

you are always such an incredible help to me ... but, Im really stumped here.

http://canboria.co.za/PHP/CALCULATOR/bond.htm

A basic bond/mortgage calculator that I have worked out using some online refs & a little modification.

How can I make this script work out the details on page loading  (i did try action onload but, didnt do the trick ... kept running a loop & times out)

Ideally, I want to have that each time a value is altered, it should work out the REPAYMENT VALUE ...  any help, ideas or guidence greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you explain your problem bit more?how it run when page loading without loanamount?

Answer (score 0):

The window.onload function seems to work for me.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/J76HZ/)

By simply adding this code

```
window.onload=giveAnAnswer;
```

Comment: you seem to understand this sort of this much better than I do.

Do you have any suggestion how I can make the REPAYMENT value change automatically, as I press the UP | DOWN buttons for the Interest Rate (int_box) & the Loan (maturity_box)...

So, a sort of as you change any values the REPAYMENT (answer_box) is adjusting itself