# How to run this code automatically

Tags: forms, calculator, onload

you are always such an incredible help to me ... but, Im really stumped [here](http://canboria.co.za/PHP/CALCULATOR/bond.htm).

A basic bond/mortgage calculator that I have worked out using some online refs & a little modification.

how I can make the REPAYMENT value change automatically, as I press the UP | DOWN buttons for the Interest Rate (int_box) & the Loan (maturity_box)... So, a sort of as you change any values the REPAYMENT (answer_box) is adjusting itself.

Ideally, I want to have that each time a value is altered, it should work out the REPAYMENT VALUE ... any help, ideas or guidence greatly appreciated!

Comment: 3 questions, no accepted answers. Hard to understand what you mean by such a "incredible help". Please show some effort by displaying a minimal code example and what you have tried.

Comment: @RonniSkansing: Are there any acceptable answers?? This one is duplicate of one question anyway

Comment: [How to automatically run this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683453/how-to-automatically-run-this-code) ??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I think we agree. He has not spend one moment reading rules nor what a good question is.

Comment: Sorry guys - I really wasnt aware on this.  Wont happen again.

Comment: @JustinDallas not aware of what? Posting the same question or not reading how to ask a question? You should try to improve your existing questions.

Comment: Ronni hiya.  

I wasnt aware that posting the same question (albeit, I was dealing with a different issue in that same code), wasnt allowed.  I had stayed within that original question but, it was unanswered for a while.

As you can see from my profile - ive only asked 2 questions before on Stackoverflow - so, appologies for this mistake.  I wasnt even aware of, or thought to look up how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `increase/decrease` functions call `giveAnAnswer()` after you change the value.  This will update the repayment each time the up or down buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `giveAnAnswer()` inside `increaseRATE()` and `decreaseRATE()` methods.

Comment: awesome! thanks for that ... so (just in case anyone else reads this, or is looking for how to do it in future)....  


I adjusted each UP | DOWN elements that used:
`code`onclick="increaseRATE()"

to onclick="increaseRATE(); giveAnAnswer()"

So, it calls boths actions/events.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML events, you can do the onchange() event for when the user changes by typing. Plus, in the Javascript add a function to your buttons to recalculate the price (As mentioned by Yate).

Example onchange(): http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp

```
<input name="Principal" type="text" class="bondtextbox" id="principal_box" value="2550000" onchange="giveAnAnswer()" />
```

Edit: Made my solution clearer. And added example for Principal textfield.